# PHP Warning: require_once failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, opencart, internal-server-error, vqmod

I am sure about the codes but it seems it has an error.. 500 internal error.. and when i check it to error logs.. it appears this bug:

> PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/qualityfoodequipment/public_html/system/startup.php) 
>   [function.require-once]: 
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ququ6475/public_html/index.php on line 23
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: 
>   Failed opening required '/home/qualityfoodequipment/public_html/system/startup.php' 
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') 
>   in /home/ququ6475/public_html/index.php on line 23

On index.php line 23:

```
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));
```

On config.php DIR:

```
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/qualityfoodequipment/public_html/system/');
```

Pease help me with this guys!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: What have you tried to debug your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are executing index.php of ququ6475 user and trying to include a file which belongs to another user (qualityfoodequipment).

May be the included file doesnt exists, or ququ6475 user doesnt have enough privileges to read it, or you have DIR_SYSTEM configured with the wrong username.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507